# How to upgrade from Visual Studio 2008 standard to professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation

I need to upgrade from Visual Studio 2008 standard to professional. Do I then need to unistall the standard version before installing professional? Are there any known issues?

thanks,

Asa

Answer (score 2):

You can install professional version over standard.
VS doesn't support on the fly upgrade - fill new licence key => new version.
But you can't two different editions of one version Visual Studio.

This is not possible on the same system

1. VS 2008 Standard edition
2. VS 2008 Professional edition

This is possible on the same system

1. VS 2005 Standard edition
2. VS 2008 Professional edition

If you have MSDN version, install over.

Comment: Hi, it's a MSDN subscription and has a built in key (not known to me). Can I then just overwrite the current standard version?

thanks, Asa

Comment: Asa, in case you didn't notice the update, yes, you can just install over the standard install.

I'm in the same boat and Google returned this, and nothing else, for an 'issues' query. There's no reason you couldn't first remove standard, and then install professional, if you were worried about it.

Comment: And while you'll have the ability to use your previous settings, it's generally a good idea to backup your current settings (Tools > Import and Export Settings...) before/after upgrading. If you installed SP1, you'll want to install it again.

Answer (score 2):

I just upgraded for Standard to Professional by installing Profressional overtop of Standard with no problems.  It kept my settings, history and plugins.  Just go for it!

Answer (score 0):

goto addremove and from there click on modify once it is in modify stage  insert your professional key there...

Comment: This is not possible, because on instalation media is only one version of VS and professional edition have more features and others applications then standard edition.